How are Chinese two - part allegorical sayings created?
How are Chinese two-part allegorical sayings created? What are the processes and methods behind their creation? Are there specific cultural backgrounds or historical origins that contribute to their formation? I am really curious about this and hope to understand the mystery behind the creation of these unique language expressions.

Such as allegorical that you said.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiehouyu

https://zh.wiktionary.org/zh-hant/Category:%E6%AD%87%E5%90%8E%E8%AF%AD

There are similar types of expressions in English; some of which you may not even be aware of their second part.

“Speak of the devil...” (full phrase: “Speak of the devil and he shall appear.”)
“If the shoe fits...” (full phrase: “If the shoe fits, wear it.”)
“Curiosity killed the cat...” (full phrase: “Curiosity killed the cat, but satisfaction brought it back.”)

These are sometimes referred to as truncated idioms and are a common feature in many languages.
What was the method of their creation? What were their backgrounds?
I am sure most would be difficult to pin down, aside from folk renderings - which would often most likely not be very accurate.
Asking about them as a whole would be difficult to give any sort of concrete response. As you can probably see with the English examples above. But at least, maybe they won't feel so exotic or foreign seeing the English counterparts.
Now, make like a banana——...

Make like a banana——Bend it like Beckham? or Yellow on the outside, white on the inside? or Dangerous when peeled / exposed? or Going berserk? or Attractive only to monkeys?

@WayneCheah It’s a set idiomatic phrase, I’m sure you can work it out.

Just like how to create puns, it is all about creativity. Actually I found another English pun database and a English pun generator, so there maybe exits such websites in Chinese? Alternatively you may use language AI for help, just type 创作一段关于xxx的歇后语/create a piece of xiehouyu about xxx, then AI will search online for the best matching.

Modern Chinese netusers keep creating such proverbs based on homonym. Such lowbrow but interesting phrases that bring joys to me. Showing most respect to 东北人. 最强歇后语对决！
I don't know details during the creation, but once you heard you immediately get them. I post examples of 牛逼, not because they are classical or cultural representative, but because one may got the word familiar through Quentin Tarantino's interview. My mind avoids me from making proper translations.

麻雀啄牛屁股——雀食牛逼
老鼠咬了牛屁股——鼠食牛逼
母牛屁股挂鞭炮——牛逼爆了
母牛坐酒缸——最牛逼了
真是小母牛按门铃——牛逼到家了


A two-part allegorical saying is a riddle followed by a brief pulse and finally providing an answer to make a humorous/witty expression, not unlike a joke, you first make a setup and then deliver the punchline
Example:
和尚打傘 - 無法無天
(Question: what is) A monk holding an umbrella(?) -- (answer:) Being lawless
Explanation:
Chinese monks have to shave their heads bald. The word 髮(hair) is pronounced the same as 法 (law), which makes 無髮(without hair) sound like 無法 (without law)
When you are holding an umbrella, you cannot see the sky directly above you, which means 無天 (without the sky)
無法無天 = No law no heaven = not obeying the law or the heaven (religious rule)
無法無天 by itself is a common idiom for "being lawless"
Side note:
The following is my favorite two-part allegorical joke:
What is 鐵棍打蘿柚 (Beating a butt with an iron rod)? The answer is a Chinese emperor
Can someone guess who that is?
It is 忽必烈 (Kublai Khan)
(屎)窟必裂 --> 忽必烈 - Beating your butt with an iron rod and it will crack

Another one, (on the monkish theme), is "To borrow a comb from a monk" -- 和尚借梳
